# How do i display an input in Python within a print statement

Tags: python-3.x

```
name = input('What is You name ')
```

this shows me only the input, I need to display 'hello' as well!!

```
print ('Hello', input(name))
```

When I try to type this :-

```
name = input('What is You name ')
print ('Hello')
input(name)
```

Why is that it displays the name directly and not the hello keyword. Could anyone please update on the same and share a coed that might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is even the [exact example in the docs](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html)

```
person = input('Enter your name: ')
print('Hello', person)
```

Comment: **Thanks** @Evan.